# How to force Light status bar in light mode?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following Info.plist config:

[image]

The codebase was in Objective-C but now 80% is migrated to Swift.

```swift
struct BottomTabBar: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)], for: .normal)
        
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    
        }
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
           
            VStack(spacing:0){
                TopNavigationBar(viewModel: sharedViewModel, backButtonAction: {})
                
                TabView {
                    // First tab with Objective-C view controller
                    PositionVCWrapper()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image("v3statusIcon")
                            Text("Status")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                        .onAppear(){
                            sharedViewModel.navigationTitle = "Status"
                            sharedViewModel.showBackButton = false

                        }
                    
                    MessageListView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image("v3messageicon")
                            Text("Message")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .font(.headline)

                        }
                        .onAppear(){
                            sharedViewModel.navigationTitle = "Recent Chats"
                            recentChatViewModel._loadLatestMessage()
                            sharedViewModel.showBackButton = false
                        }
                       
                    
                    Activity(l)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image("v3activityIcon")
                            Text("Activity")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                        .onAppear(){
                            sharedViewModel.navigationTitle = "Activity"
                            sharedViewModel.showBackButton = false
                        }
                }
                .accentColor(.white)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

Here the status bar is still appearing in dark mode. I want this to be in light mode.

When I do `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` in Swift (above code) it makes the whole app to dark mode and status to light. I want in light mode the status should look light.

Comment: Are you using the appearance proxy and setting values on singletons in view `init`s throughout the codebase? You generally shouldn't do that, because several of those might be conflicting, as views get initialized potentially as often as every screen refresh (up to 120 times per second). Depending on their order, another one somewhere else might be winning out. Do you get better results if you put that in the call to `.onAppear(_:)`?

Comment: You could also use the native SwiftUI modifier and set that view to have `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)`, but that likely has broader implications as well that you may or may not want, and might not work with `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` set to `NO` in your `Info.plist`

Comment: @MichaelHulet manipulating singleton used to be the only way to set the colors right in iOS 13 - 15. But most of them no longer work in iOS 16.

Comment: I think this is yet another one of the limitations of SwiftUI, I suggest submitting feedback to apple, they do look for issues like that and seems fix them

Comment: @timbretimbre Since iOS 7, the preferred way of setting the status bar style was by setting [`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiviewcontrollerbasedstatusbarappearance) to `YES` in your `Info.plist` and overriding [`preferredStatusBarStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle) in your view controller, but that's not really a concept SwiftUI has directly. You could subclass `UIHostingController`, but that's touchy

Comment: @MichaelHulet It really doesn't matter what was the proper way for UIKit. I am talking about SwiftUI limitations and workarounds. So changing the mentioned singletons was the way to go, until it stopped working as well. I asked about couple of such things during WWDC, and the answer was: submit a feedback, it will be looked at. So this is what I recommended

Comment: @timbretimbre Agreed, touching UIKit is bad, but that's what setting `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle` means doing. That property has been around since the dawn of iOS, but was deprecated in iOS 7 in favor of `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`. It stopped working because nobody should be relying on it anymore. Unfortunately, the only way to do it in SwiftUI directly is by using either of the view modifiers `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` or `.toolbarColorScheme(.dark)`, which have their own broader implications :/